# Python - Why is this class variable not defined in the method?

Tags: python, variables, scope

I have a python application which is as follows:

```
global_counter = 0
connections = {}

class SocketHandler():
    currentid = 0
    def open(self):
        global global_counter
        global connections
        currentid = global_counter
        global_counter += 1
        connections[currentid] = self
        print "WebSocket " + str(currentid) + " opened"

    def on_close(self):
        global connections
        print "WebSocket " + str(currentid) + " closed"
        del connections[currentid]
```

I'm getting the error:

```
NameError: global name 'currentid' is not defined
```

on the lines of "open" and "on_close" where I print that I am opening/closing the connection. I defined it in the class, why is it not in scope. Also, I have read that using global variables is bad, but I don't see a way around this. Can someone point out what I should do? Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't have implicit access to attributes inside methods, in Python.

A bare name like `currentid` in the line:

```
del connections[currentid]
```

always looks up a name in the local function scope, then in each enclosing function scope, before trying the global module scope (and then looks at built-ins as a last resort). `currentid` is a class attribute, which won't be found in any of those scopes.

To look up an attribute in Python you **always** need to specify an object in which to look. Though the lookup protocol means the object need not necessarily have the attribute itself; attribute lookup will fall back to the class of the object you specified (and the base classes, if inheritance is involved).

So this would work:

```
del connections[self.currentid]
```

However, I don't think the rest of your code is doing what you think it is either. This line in the `open` method:

```
currentid = global_counter
```

doesn't set the `currentid` attribute of your `SocketHandler` object. Assigning to a bare name *always* assigns to a local variable, unless you explicitly declare it `global` (you appear to be aware of this, since you've used the `global` keyword). So in the `open` method, `currentid` is a local function variable; its value is lost at the end of the `open` method.

In fact, your `SocketHandler` objects do not have a `currentid` attribute at all (unless there's more code you haven't shown us). Putting `currentid = 0` in the class block doesn't give all the `SocketHandler` instances a `currentid` attribute. It gives the `SocketHandler` class **itself** an attribute `currentid`; this is just as the `def open(self):` block creates an `open` attribute (storing a function) on the class object, not on each individual instance.

Reading `self.currentid` in the `on_close` method will fail to find a `currentid` attribute in the object `self`, so Python will look at the class of `self` which is `SocketHandler`. That object *does* have a `currentid` value, so the result of reading `self.currentid` will be `0`, whether or not you've previously run `open` on that `SocketHandler`.

If you meant to store the `currentid` as an instance variable in each `SocketHandler`, then the line in `open` would need to be:

```
self.currentid = global_counter
```

This assigns to the `currentid` attribute of the object referred to by `self`. You would also then need to change all the other references to `currentid` in your methods to `self.currentid`.

Comment: My current Python course doesn't cover this topic. You explained this topic in such great detail, which was incredibly helpful and I learned a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

`currentid` should be `self.currentid` since it is a class variable.

Comment: Why is this that much upvoted? -- the code in the exampe above will no longer break with NameError, but will break with a severe logical error if only this replacement is made.

Comment: @jsbueno: What do you mean? The only other variables being modified are globals.

Comment: @Blender How likely do you think it is that the OP intended to have a local variable with the same name as the class attribute inside the `open` method? And to have the `on_close` method always `del connections[0]`?

Comment: @Ben: Sorry, I read jsbueno's comment as saying that there will be a parsing error in the script, not a runtime error.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out to put self.currentid in both methods, it all runs accorrding to plan.

Answer (score 1):

`currentid` is instance attribute, so use `self.currentid` instead of `currentid`:

```
def on_close(self):
        global connections
        print "WebSocket " + str(self.currentid) + " closed"
        del connections[self.currentid]
```